# I am between academic institutions. If I submit a paper what do I say my affiliation is?

Tags: publications, ethics, affiliation

Basically, I was a student at University Y when I wrote a paper. I am no longer a student there, but work at Company Z.

Do I still list University Y as my institutional affiliation? Their resources helped make the paper possible and all of it was written at University Y.

But on the other hand, I am currently working at Company Z.

Comment: After I left my previous academic institution, I co-authored a paper with a former colleague.  My affiliation was "Independent Researcher", and I used an email tied to my personal domain (instead of, say, my personal gmail).

Comment: Actually, this has been asked several times in different forms. Look at the posts with [tag:affiliation] for more.

Comment: A note updating contact information should be fine. Like university xyz. X. Y. is now at zyx.