# Does affiliation on a paper without funding matter?

Tags: publications, conference, affiliation

I graduated from my undergraduate program two years ago with a major in Computer Science. During my undergraduate studies, I did research with a professor, and published under the university's affiliation; (Department of Computer Science, Uni Name).

I am currently working in a company which I will refer to as G. I recently worked on a research idea during my weekends which led to an accepted paper in a conference. I would publish with G as an affiliation, except G has a ridiculous 3 month process to allow an employee to use them as an affiliation in a research paper, while the deadline for modifying personal information in the accepted paper is in a month.

My question is, can I add my undergraduate school as my affiliation? The work was in no way or form sponsored by G or my undergraduate school.

Comment: No, you are not currently affiliated with your undergraduate school, so that would be dishonest. However, it’s perfectly fine not to have an affiliation.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/132511/i-am-between-academic-institutions-if-i-submit-a-paper-what-do-i-say-my-affilia

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1078/is-it-acceptable-to-publish-a-paper-using-an-affiliation-with-a-former-employer

Comment: The system won't let me mark this as duplicate of the best match, but rather the question that the best match is a duplicate of.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19710/what-to-put-in-affiliation-field-when-submitting-paper-without-affiliation

Comment: Do not commit affiliation fraud.  "Does affiliation on a paper without funding matter?" It is up to the preferences of the institution.

Comment: @DanRomik and Anonymous Physicist: Thanks, I just changed it to "None". Thank you for letting me know this was not acceptable

Comment: Actually, list yourself as "Independent Researcher" rather than "none". This is valid if your current employer hasn't supported your research.

Comment: Caution: before submitting, check the terms of your employment contract with G to see whether G owns the copyright in the paper; and if your employment contract with G doesn't say clearly one way or the other, check local public law to see what the default position is with respect the ownership of copyright in works produced by employees.  There's a small but non-zero probability that the result will be that you discover you can't submit the paper at all without G's permission, in which case they might insist on you waiting for their ridiculous 3 month process.